# Animating (Translation) Horizontal listview items

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, translate-animation, horizontallist

I've an horizontal listview with several textviews. I want to translate (animate) these textviews (items) only from right to left as a circular way, while click a button. Not translate the horizontal listview layout. Is this possible?

Edit:

For this horizontal listview, i used an adapter to load the values into that list.

Like this:

```
private static String[] dataObjects = new String[]{ "Text #1",
    "Text #2",
    "Text #3","Text #4","Text #5","Text #6","Text #7","Text #8","Text #9","Text #10" };

private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataObjects.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressLint({ "ViewHolder", "InflateParams" })
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
        //Button button = (Button) retval.findViewById(R.id.clickbutton);
        //button.setOnClickListener(mOnButtonClicked);
        title.setText(dataObjects[position]);

        return retval;
    }       

};
```

And set this adapter to the horizontal listview as:

```
listView=(HorizontalListView)findViewById(R.id.simple_list);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: yes it is possible. what do you mean by `circular way`?

Comment: @Ali, That means translate these textviews from starting point of this textview to end of parent, that is Horizontal listview and then again translate from endpoint of parent to itself. Just like a process of marquee tag in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Make translate.xml in res -> anim directory. Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
 android:duration="500"
 android:fillAfter="true"
 android:fromXDelta="100%"
 android:toXDelta="0%" >
  />
```

Change percentages in `android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"` to fit your needs. Now use :

```
animationT = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(myContext,
        R.anim.translate);

//put inside your clickListener
button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    textView1.startAnimation(animationT);
    textView2.startAnimation(animationT);
    textView3.startAnimation(animationT);
});
```

Comment: I don't want to translate a single textview at a time. Once i clicked a button, then translate the all textviews inside of the horizontal listview layout only. Like a marquee tag working principle in HTML. That's it

Comment: So whats the problem, you can apply same animation to all textViews.

Comment: Just see the my updated question... I think that if i've hundreds or thousands of values in the list, then your code is not efficient or not fit to this criteria.

Comment: put textView.startanimation inside getview

Comment: based your ans, it's animate every time that view will be added. I want to animate, only when i'm click a button. Don't forgot my basic constraints....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66200/discussion-between-bosco-and-mohammed-ali).